# Python - elevator prob

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7 and getting below error on my code -

```
def format_output(self, distance, log):
    log.append(distance)
    str = ''

    for j in log:
        if j == log[-1]:
            str += '(%d)'
        else:
            str += '%d '

    print str % (tuple(log))
```

And the error:

```
print str % (tuple(log))
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to make it correct?

Comment: Can you add an example of input you are passing and output you expect to be printed.

Comment: You shouldn't use reserved words (`str`) for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
def format_output(self, distance, log):
log.append(distance)
str1 = ''

for j in log:
    if j == log[-1]:
        str1 += '(%d)'
    else:
        str1 += '(%d)'

print (str1 % (tuple(log)))
```

this is not gonna give you any syntax error, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Kedar and other as well.